# update column with other repeat column

Tags: sql, oracle

I use `PL/SQL`. I have a table like this

```
a   |  b
---------
111 |
111 |
222 |
333 |
333 |
333 |
444 |
444 |
```

I want use `update` the column `b`, the result become

```
a   |  b
---------
111 |  1
111 |  2
222 |  1
333 |  1
333 |  2
333 |  3
444 |  1
444 |  2
```

How to do it? Thanks.

**edit**

The `b` will start from 1, according `a`'s count plus one.

Comment: What is the logic for the values in column b?

Comment: I have increasing the `b`'s statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this query:

```
update Table1 t1 set t1.b = 
(SELECT r FROM (select ROWID rid,row_number() over(PARTITION BY a ORDER BY a) r 
from Table1) t2 where t1.ROWID = t2.rid);
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc8d7/1)

Comment: @LLL [Same result can be achieved](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0ba67/4) by using `merge` statement, as well. But, it would be better not to do the update at all. Create a view and keep your data up to date. What will you do when you make some changes(delete a row, update the `a` column) to that table, run the update statement again?

Comment: Thanks for your comment,but i just answer the question,the other things about the database architecture is not my job in this question.

Comment: Absolutely, there is nothing against your answer. I left that comment for @LLL.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new table, or a view, with the following SQL:

```
select a.a,row_number() over (partition by a order by a) as b from table
```

Direct Update will not work, because there's no primary/unique key in your table.